# What is my problem with ASP.NET pubslishing?

Tags: asp.net, linq, publishing

I am done testing my site and I want to upload it to a site like this

http://www.university.edu/mydepartment/myname

the admin told me the server runs on .NET 3.5. So i used Linq ...

now i tried to upload the site by two ways:

when i just copy everything (with modification of web.config database settings) i get an error:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name
> 'DataClassesDataContext' could not be
> found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
> Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082;
> ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

Note here it says version 2.0
did he just lie to me? or its my configuration mistake?

anyway, i added the reference, nothing changes.

I tried also publishing (Build, publish) with option to keep the pre-comiled site updatable, and I get one line saying:

> this is a makefile and should be
> deleted!

what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't find your DBML file, or your DBML file isn't called "DataClasses.dbml". Also, the .NET Framework Version is not lying. It is reporting the CLR version, which is still 2.0 for the 3.5 .NET Framework.

Comment: I think you're right. The dataclasses.dbml is inside app_code folder and it has not been uploaded by the publish wizard.

but how to solve this?

Comment: btw, My MS VS 2008 Version 9.0.30729.1 SP